# Graph Explorer says access denied for view list of Channels. Using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: graph, channel, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

[visual representation of graph explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3D5Q.png)
***"Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadsS2SRequest."***
Today morning my app failed and when I digged enough I realize that somehow my permission to list the channels is denied. Weird part is if i put channels Id after channels in API, i get valid response.

I went to the documentation and made sure I have groupreadwrite permission, all of the sudden api for viewing channels of specific teams gives me 
"Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadsS2SRequest." error. Sys admin says that no permissions has been changed.

I would expect graph explorer to list all the channels in that specific teams with the v1 endpoint /teams/teamId/channels

Comment: It works at my side. Maybe it is a temporary system error. Could you please have another try? Or grant permissions again?

Comment: May I know if you were a member of that team?

Comment: @Ashok Subedi There was a issue going on with List Channel Graph Api which has been fixed now. Could you please try this again and let us know if the issue is solved?

Comment: @JackJia I am the member and owner of the team. I does works now

Comment: Thank you @Gousia-MSFT I did find out that yesterday before day ended. the issue started yesterday and fixed yesterday for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and yes the issue has been fixed. Whole day I had to debug my app to figure out where did the code went wrong. Sometimes it is better look at the source. I checked with Microsoftgraph dotnet issues forum and found out that channel api has some issue. Graph explorer really helped me understand that it was not my code. By the way, I thought since they are deploying channel with private members features. I thought that could be the reason behind it. Thank you for the all the above comments. I wish there is a page where microsoft could tell us in the future if there is any api that is not working